# Flutter app and web site connected to a same database

Tags: database, wordpress, flutter

I want to create an app with Flutter and also a web site with WordPress. However, I don't know if it is possible to connect both oh my site and app to a unique database and I don't find any document on it. Indeed, I want my customers to be able to log in them on both. Do you know if it is possible or not and have you any document that could help me ?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is actually a very good article on how to proceed to make a Wordpress connection throught your app made with Flutter:
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/flutter-app-connection/

Also, don't forgot, that every wordpress have a public API (by accessing {wordpressWebsiteUrl}/wp-json) where you can get your post etc...